# How to hide the listbox in php code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$options = array(
              'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
              'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
              'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
              'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
            );    echo form_dropdown('some_name', $options, '  ' ,'id='some_id');
```

Now i want to hide this listbox .. How do i do this??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide? you mean with javascript? You're not very clear in your question, so if I misunderstood just let know

```
  $options = array(........);
  echo form_dropdown('some_name',$options,'','id="some_id"');
```

Hiding:

Using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#some_id').hide('fast');
});
```

Or with CSS:

```
#some_id { display:none; }  /* this will also free up the space used by the dropdown*/
#some_id { visibility:hidden; } /* this just makes it invisible, but the space it occupies its preserved*/
```

Note that as forth parameter to the form_dropdown() you pass a string, so you could give it an id, a class, an onlick event, whatever. So, you can give it a `'class="invisible" id="some_id" onclick="myfunction"'` and manage it's visibility with that.

Comment: Sorry for the unclearity of the question.. Can i hide it by setting some property of form_dropdown

Comment: if you mean a kinda "hidden dropdown" like it were an hidden input the answer is NO, you can't. But, as I said, you can give it a class name that makes it invisibile, so it's pretty much the same